# ubuntu genymotion broken display

Tags: android, ubuntu, genymotion

Help me please. I am new to Android development, trying to build my first project.

My system is:
 - ubuntu 12.04 32bit
 - virtualbox 4.3.2
 - genymotion-2.3.1_x86
 - samsung q210

I try to start genymotion, but nothing works. Images below:

[image: main screen]

When I press something (e.g. touch the screen) the screen blinks, but doesn't respond.

[image: half the main screen]

I have tried lots of phones available and different android versions. Everything is the same.
Please, help me out or just give a hint about fixing it.

P.S. I have tried to use the standard android emulator, but my processor doesn't support KVM

Comment: Which video driver are you using? if your are using the open source one, you could try to use the proprietary driver. I fear your computer is too old to run Genymotion or the Android SDK Emulator.